# Обновление данных Dom-дерева в Javascript

Tags: javascript

Проблема в следующем, при загрузке страницы javascript'ом создаются элементы, затем идёт попытка их изменить, но элементы не видны,есть ли какой-нибудь способ обновить иформацию об этих элементах?

http://jsfiddle.net/srL66/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOM-дерево обновляется при любом изменении любого элемента.

Если старые элементы пропадают, а новые не появляются, скорее всего где-то ошибка в вашем коде. Нажмите ctrl+shift+j чтоб вызвать консоль браузера и проверить это. Если ошибки есть, там будет указано, где они. Если нет - выложите ваш код на jsbin или jsfiddle и мы попробуем разобраться, в чём проблема.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/srL66/2/
вот ссылка, консоль пишет, что объектов нет:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of undefined

Comment: сорри, нашёл ошибку) 
просто забыл убрать лишнее, а изза ошибки код прекращался))